# How to use a variable list as a target in a Makefile?

Tags: arrays, variables, makefile, target

Suppose I am working on a makefile and I have the following variable declaration at the top:

```
FILES = file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
```

Now suppose I want to compile each of those with a special command without specifying each target like this:

```
file1.o : file1.cpp
    custom_command file1.cpp
file2.o : file2.cpp
    custom_command file2.cpp
file3.o : file3.cpp
    custom_command file3.cpp
```

Is there a better way to do this using the `$(FILES)` variable I declared above?

Something like:

```
$(FILES:.cpp=.o) : $(FILES)
    custom_command $(FILES)
```

...only it needs to do this for each file in the `$(FILES)` variable.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes. There are what are known as *pattern rules*. An example is the easiest to understand:

```
%.o: %.cpp
       $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

(remember that Makefiles *require* tabs). This rule describes how to make an object file from a cpp file.

If you do not want such a broad rule, you can use what are called static patterns:

```
objects = file1.o file2.o file3.o

all: $(objects)

$(objects): %.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Here's the section on [static pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/make/Static-Usage.html) and [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/make/Pattern-Examples.html) in the GNU Make manual.

Answer (score 12):

You *can* do that, as per the following:

```
SRCS=a.c b.c
OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
        cc -c -o a.o a.c
        cc -c -o b.o b.c
```

but you have to remember that the dependencies are complete - it assumes that `a.o` depends on `b.c` as well which is probably not the case.

What you're probably after is a single rule on how to turn one file type into another:

```
SRCS=a.c b.c
OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJS)

.c.o:
        gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

`.c.o` is such a rule which states what commands to run to turn a `.c` file into a `.o` file. In the actual command, `$@` is replaced with the specific target and `$<` is replaced with the name of the first prerequisite.

There are many other *automatic variables* you can use, look them up with `info make` or look for a good book on `make` if you don't have the `info` stuff available.

Comment: Ya, that's pretty much what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Another way to specify dependencies exactly is to use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) of the prerequisites (GNU Make specific feature).

Comment: FYI- for anyone looking for documentation - the `.c.o` rule is called a [suffix rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) in GNU-make's parlance.  GNU-make recommends using pattern rules over suffix rules.

Answer (score 1):

```
SRCS = a.c b.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

.c.o:
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

Though `$<` isn't quite portable (IIRC, bsdmake has the meaning of `$^` and `$<` exactly swapped to what gmake uses), this is the default recipe for `.c.o` that would be in effect in either implementation.